# apnsService problem

Tags: iphone, grails, groovy, apple-push-notifications

I am using the apns plugin in my app, it is running fine, but when a generate a war file and publish in my QA env, I`m getting the follow error"

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'apnsService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'password'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'password': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

I have NO idea what is going on?! any idea?!

cheers!

Comment: It would help to post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't configure the password and other required attributes as described in the plugin docs: http://grails.org/plugin/apns

That error will happen when a missing attribute is retrieved from the config. Since it's a `ConfigObject`, missing attributes return a new `ConfigObject`. This is to support the syntax `config.foo.bar.baz = 'wahoo'` - each dotted property access accesses the existing `ConfigObject` or creates and stores a new one if it doesn't.

Comment: exactly! . it was missing the password for the new environment! but the problem was.. i added the password, and was still broken!. but after a "grails clean" it worked fine!... thanks!!